# Using Resx files without App_GlobalResources folder

Tags: asp.net

We use RESX files to manage translatable text labels published from a Content Management System.

In the past we would simply publish the labels to the folder App_GlobalResources folder, and use the following code to retrieve a label from the application:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("labels", "key_name")
```

However, we've recently worked on an implementation that has a PrecompiledApp.Config file.

I understand this means we can't have a App_GlobalResources folder.

Is there anyway we can continue to use resx files in this scenario?